# How do I update a module script's variables in roblox studio?

Tags: lua, roblox

So I have `scriptOne` (module) and `scriptTwo` (local script I think). I use `scriptTwo` to `require()` and change the variables with that. But how do I update the values in `scriptOne` (that I also want to access from other scripts as well) to these new values?

scriptOne code

```
local module = {}

module.test = 100

while true do 
    wait(1)
    print(module.test)
end

return module
```

scriptTwo code

```
local data = require(workspace.playerStats)

data.test = 0
```

Comment: it is not quite clear to me what you're asking here. `data` and `module` refer to the same table. how does your code's behaviour differ from what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing variables inside of a modulescript is global, change a variable and every script using the module gets the new variable

the reason why the code you provided doesnt work is because of the while loop. the loop yields and cant proceed, meaning it cant also return the module so the server script is waiting forever.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the while loop in the ModuleScript. ModuleScripts are used by `require()` to share variables. In your case, your ModuleScript has a infinite loop, which doesn't let `require()` return, and gets the second script stuck. You are probably using the while loop for debugging the variable, so I'd recommend moving it to the second script.